# ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from partially initialized module 'celery' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: django, celery

With latest version of celery, in python 3.10.6,  I am getting the above error, trace back is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/biju/Desktop/trial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/biju/Desktop/trial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/biju/Desktop/trial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/biju/Desktop/trial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/biju/Desktop/trial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/biju/Desktop/trial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/biju/Desktop/trial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/biju/Desktop/trial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/biju/Desktop/trial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_celery_beat/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    from celery import current_app, schedules
  File "/home/biju/Desktop/trial/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from partially initialized module 'celery' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

insatalled importlib-metadata==4.13.0, but error persists, Django version is 3.2

Comment: Your python script is named `celery.py`, and so `import celery` finds that module instead of the real one.  Name your script something else.

Comment: thanks, it is working after the fix you suggested